# Как ссылаться на DLL в решении в VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

В VS2013 есть решение с проектами на С++. Один главный, а остальные планируется оформить в виде динамических библиотек. Как правильно ссылаться на эти библиотеки/проекты из главного? Необходимо в свойствах главного всё прописывать вручную (пути к *.h, *.lib, *.dll )? Или можно как-то проще? В чём тогда смысл решения?

Comment: В каждом проекте в свойствах - General - перечисленны зависимости - добавляете все проекты от которых текущий зависит (это влияет на порядок построения проектов) и ставите галочку - линковать зависимости или нет - это для линковщика. Пути на заголовочные файлы надо прописывать (на вкладке С++) но лучше использовать макро типа $(SolutionDir)/subproj/include, чтоб при переносе проекта с места на место пути менять не приходилось

Comment: 0. Ну сначала ответьте на вопрос, зачем вообще понадобились отдельные dll.  1. Если dll подключаются в проект через соответствующую lib, то при сборке нужна будет только lib, а dll понадобится только при запуске.

Comment: @Artemy Vysotsky Спасибо, как раз то, что и интересовало)

Comment: @Alex Titov смысл не просто в сборке, а еще в отладке, чтобы не прописывать path или не заниматься копированием dll.